# Extract parameter value from url using regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex, url

This should be very simple (when you know the answer). From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412467/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-php)

I want to give the posted solution a try. My question is:

How to get the parameter value of a given URL using JavaScript regular expressions?

I have:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ahg6qcgoay4
```

I need:

```
Ahg6qcgoay4
```

I tried:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch\\?v=(w{11})
```

But: I suck...

Comment: checkout also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738351/recommendation-for-javascript-url-manipulation-library-api

Comment: @dfa: I might need that in the future, thanks for the link. I guess I should probably get this regexp right first :)

Comment: '/v=[0-9A-Za-z]*/' 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706986/php-getting-url-variable-with-preg-match

Comment: Checkout the javascript module [get-video-id](https://github.com/radiovisual/get-video-id) that will extract the Youtube id from any known Youtube url format (including embed strings). It doesn't use one monolithic regex, but it employs a few regex's to find the different patterns.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You almost had it, just need to escape special regex chars:

```
regex = /http\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([\w-]{11})/;

url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ahg6qcgoay4';
id = url.match(regex)[1]; // id = 'Ahg6qcgoay4'
```

**Edit:** Fix for regex by [soupagain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280557/extract-parameter-value-from-url-using-regular-expressions#comment2200253_1280572).

Comment: Should probably also put in a test for if the match fails, such as var m = url.match(regex); id = (m && m.length > 1) ? m[1] : null;

Comment: Don't know how to edit answers, but the above answer is incorrect, as it fails with video IDs containing the - dash character.

Therefore the regex should be:

/http\:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([\w-]{11})/

Answer (score 22):

Why dont you take the string and split it

Example on the url

```
var url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?p=DB852818BF378DAC&v=1q-k-uN73Gk"
```

you can do a split as

```
var params = url.split("?")[1].split("&");
```

You will get array of strings with params as name value pairs with "=" as the delimiter.

Comment: that is a original idea, +1 for that, but I recommend using HttpUtility.ParseQueryString if you can live with referencing System.Web.dll, and not reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 5):

Not tested but this should work:

```
/\?v=([a-z0-9\-]+)\&?/i
```

Comment: some youtube urls have a - as well, such as...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22hUHCr-Tos

Comment: @MyWhriledView Updated for the hyphen

Answer (score 5):

v is a query parameter, technically you need to consider cases ala: http://www.youtube.com/watch?p=DB852818BF378DAC&v=1q-k-uN73Gk

In .NET I would recommend to use `System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url)["v"];
```

And you don't even need to check the key, as it will return null if the key is not in the collection.

Comment: Strictly speaking this should be var playlist = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri(url).Query)["v"];  because ParseQueryString is looking for a query string, not a whole URL.

Comment: Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20268544/portable-class-library-pcl-version-of-httputility-parsequerystring

Comment: Why is this answer in .NET when the OP has tagged JS?

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is Old and already answered but this can also be a solution

```
\b[\w-]+$
```

and I checked these two URLs

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ahg6qcgoay4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22hUHCr-Tos
```

[DEMO](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=94364)

Answer (score 1):

I use seperate custom functions which gets all URL Parameters and URL parts .
For URL parameters, (which is the final part of an URI String, http://domain.tld/urlpart/**?x=a&y=b**

```
    function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
    }
```

The above function will return an array consisting of url variables.

For URL Parts or functions, (which is http://domain.tld/**urlpart**/?x=a&y=b
I use a simple uri split,

```
function getUrlParams() { 
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.split('/' );
    return parts;
}
```

You can even combine them both to be able to use with a single call in a page or in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This RegEx supports many YouTube url formats.

```js
/^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:m\.|www\.)?(?:youtu\.be\/|youtube\.com\/(?:embed\/|v\/|watch\?v=|shorts\/|watch\?.+&v=))((\w|-){11})(?:\S+)?$/
```

Supported url formats

```js
const ytUrlFormats = {
  normal: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12345678901',
  share: 'https://youtu.be/12345678902',
  shareWithStartTime: 'https://youtu.be/12345678903?t=6',
  mobileBrowserUrl: 'https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=12345678904&list=RD12345678901&start_radio=1',
  long: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12345678905&list=RD12345678905&start_radio=1&rv=smKgVuS',
  longWithStartTime: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12345678906&list=RD12345678901&start_radio=1&rv=12345678901&t=38',
  shorts: 'https://youtube.com/shorts/12345678907',
};
```

You can check this in the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAnlAqgJwDYDETILYEMoQwC8MA3gFAwxhZ6oBcMA5ABZRQAOE9A9DwO6CAdHBABXKGIBGAUyGhsA-MBYB%20AG5EAjACYAzABYArADYA7AA4AnAAYtTADSUYEFrmQzGrdl149REmJCsjy6hqaWtjqOzq7uMgDqAJZQLADKUO5QACpJ2J7MbJzcfAGSwTKh%20sbm1jZ6qlBEJjFU2CBSSagyAELIIPwQMsgoDIU%20JTzYIuKSsvIgivzKapphNZE2BgBkqEnQRABKACLrEXVa29BZAPrIuAAmSSDarTCo4ADmXkW%20fIL8GaBeYKJRQFQabTVc62Iy7fZNE5nWqwq6ZZBQO6PZ7abbITQQbAAaU%20ADUxGk3h8wJ9kqkMllcvkfhM-ACgXM5KDluDVlDwiibCZ4QckdDBZdrhisU8Xpd8fyNhdtk09BY3q4sAQWcU-GVpFzFjxNRiIFUBZszDEAL4AbnI5FAkFgeF5hxknwAogAPYjUGT8GDur3ejgACh4AD0w6p6L8ILGADo8ZMASlUMfo2ETQgAPgCc%20nM-qc7Jk7n9WWFtmeJmZNhZA9y%20pyzyVInIbmTQRWysO0IANTbTSp1NhsOJ-i5gC0qdIWi01rHSbSA-TABIeKn7eQAPJSABWMmAUCEAGsZHAIGGEKNMDh8BBU0IAGZYT24FRhsRoe%20u4gAHxkM4TrQDAP6oH6t6-rQj4ANoQX%20%20AwLghAXqIL4wFAcAcDIICYdBGCwQQAC69pUKBLorAA4v0YhcH6EFCK6X4sSwwY%20tuzhJJhYYAIRsbR4hcKmwFUBR4AQCA3RCB8nxhgABuguBdDIDxYSAMCfDIsAAJLHDAb7IIw66kBB1oKVx4kwB4kjIGA5EwNaDoSZA0lyHJimmYhxHWiZpCCXRXBwVoJEWVxS5AA) (run & check in the console)