# Parsing Youtube URLs

Tags: javascript, regex, youtube

I'm trying to get all Youtube video IDs from string like this:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OovKTBO4aQs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOQsYk8cbnE https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97aiSGxmizg
```

Following to [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/how-do-i-retrieve-all-matches-for-a-regular-expression-in-javascript) I wrote code:

```
var re = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch(?:\.php)?\?.*v=)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/g,
    str = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OovKTBO4aQs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOQsYk8cbnE https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97aiSGxmizg',
    match;

while (match = re.exec(str)) {
   if (match.index === re.lastIndex) {
      re.lastIndex++;
   }

   console.log(match[1]);
}
```

But `console.log` shows only last ID `97aiSGxmizg`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many matches do you expect? Do you also need to match `DOQsYk8cbnE` in `https://www.youtube.com watch?v=DOQsYk8cbnE`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew three matches: OovKTBO4aQs, DOQsYk8cbnE and 97aiSGxmizg

Comment: where you get this strange `str`? maybe you can ask for array instead?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/GBSiXs/1/

Comment: if you are only getting youtube URLs, then why don't you just check for "v=" (some value) " "

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sorry, there's was a typo in `str`. Now it's ok, but code is still doesn't work as I want

Comment: @DanielGale in common case, youtube has many types of URLs, so I took this regex because it works for all URLs types

Comment: @mplungjan of course I can split string with spaces, but I suppose it is not optimal decision

Comment: @TroyHambleton your regexp is not correct. its matching spaces between them

Comment: @ShrihariBalasubramani but it works well here https://regex101.com/r/Peu4Oq/1

Comment: @ShrihariBalasubramani how can I update this regexp to make it work? https://regex101.com/r/Peu4Oq/2

Comment: var re = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch(?:\.php)?\?[^ ]*v=)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/g;  Please check my answer for more

Comment: @TroyHambleton I don't think you are covering all the scenarios. YouTube URLs come in several flavors other than `v=` - While this question doesn't answer your question and is php related it does lists a few of the YouTube URL formats in the question itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693218/youtube-i-d-parsing-for-new-url-formats such as `http://youtu.be/97aiSGxmizg` or `http://www.youtube.com/v/97aiSGxmizg`

Comment: @TroyHambleton in combination with map, not an issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You regex is not correct.

The correct regex would be like this:

```js
var re = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch(?:\.php)?\?[^ ]*v=)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/g;

var str = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OovKTBO4aQs jiberish https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOQsYk8cbnE  jiberish a https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97aiSGxmizg'
console.log(str.match(re))
```

Comment: As you can see in the [mcve] I made from your answer, the result is not a list of IDs since you do not show the captures

Answer (score 1):

Assuming v=something, try this (regex from [Extract parameter value from url using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280557/extract-parameter-value-from-url-using-regular-expressions))

```js
var regex = /\?v=([a-z0-9\-]+)\&?/gi, matches = [], index=1;
urls = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OovKTBO4aQs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOQsYk8cbnE https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97aiSGxmizg";
while (match = regex.exec(urls)) matches.push(match[index])
console.log(matches)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the posted string's format, `v=id`, one can do something as simple as split the string at space  and the again, combined with `reduce()`, at `v=`, to get the successfully split'ed id's.

*I also used an anonymous function `(function(){...})();` to only have to run the split once.*

Stack snippet

```js
var str = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OovKTBO4aQs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOQsYk8cbnE https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97aiSGxmizg';

var list = str.split(' ').reduce(function(r, e) {
  (function(i){
    if (i.length > 1) r.push(i[1]);
  })(e.split('v='));  
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(list);
```

---

As mentioned, if there are other formats, one can easily use a regex, e.g.

Stack snippet

```js
var str = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OovKTBO4aQs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOQsYk8cbnE https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97aiSGxmizg http://www.youtube.com/v/-wtIMTCHWuI http://youtu.be/-DOQsYk8cbnE';

var list = str.split(' ').reduce(function(r, e) {
  (function(i){
    if (i.length > 1) r.push(i[1]);
  })(e.split(/v=|v\/-|be\/-/));
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

The capture group will only match the last match in that string.

Split the strings into an array and log them there:

```js
var re = /(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:youtu\.be\/|(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch(?:\.php)?\?.*v=)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/g,
  str = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OovKTBO4aQs https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DOQsYk8cbnE https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=97aiSGxmizg',
  strs = str.split(' ');


strs.forEach((str) => {
  var match;
  while (match = re.exec(str)) {
    if (match.index === re.lastIndex) {
      re.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log(match[1]);
  }
})
```

Comment: No need to split on space