# Regex for url line

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have a next URL line:

http://localhost:3333/my-project/resources/index.html?q=PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGlu+&roles=Example

I need get parameters, which have after ?q= and &roles=

Please help me what kind of regular expressions I can be used?

Comment: why not use URLSearchParams to get parameters directly?

Comment: what i need only is the regular expression

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract parameter value from url using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280557/extract-parameter-value-from-url-using-regular-expressions)