# regex - trying to auto embed youtube videos

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to embed YouTube videos in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412467/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-php)

```
function youtube($string)
{
preg_match('#(v\/|watch\?v=)([\w\-]+)#', $string, $match);
  return preg_replace(
    '#((http://)?(www.)?youtube\.com/watch\?[=a-z0-9&_]+)#i',
    "<div align=\"center\"><iframe title=\"YouTube video player\" width=\"480\" height=\"390\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$match[2]\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>",
    $string);
}
```

This function almost works, but since the "&" character is turned into "&amp;" it doesn't quite get rid of the whole URL.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRcUzu_xdJI&feature=feedu

For example returns

*embedded video*&amp;feature=feedu

How would I need to modify the second regex?

```
#((http://)?(www.)?youtube\.com/watch\?[=a-z0-9&_]+)#i
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412467/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is just the `&amp;` in the URL string, then extend the character class in your second regex. It only needs to also replace the `;` as well:

```
#((http://)?(www.)?youtube\.com/watch\?[=a-z0-9&_;]+)#i
```

It might make more sense to match for `\S+` however. There might be other unexpected parameters in that string, and thus more leftovers if your character class is too strict.