# youtube video post with php

Tags: php, youtube, video-streaming

I've a input form which i want to post a youtube video link. For example:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0MMNsUgaUd0&NR=1&feature=endscreen
   or
   http://youtu.be/0MMNsUgaUd0

So, whatever link i provided in the input box it's should be show a video on my website. How can i do this with php. 
Any Idea?

Comment: regular expressions. I added the tag to get relevant people here ;)

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412467/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use preg_replace (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) this will search the youtube url and replace with youtube object code.