# youtube video doesn't play on mozilla firefox : html embed

Tags: html, firefox, youtube, embed, mozilla

I have this code:

```
echo '<embed src="'.$data['band_video_1'].'" height="300" width="453">';
```

to display a Youtube video.. It works fine in Google Chrome but not in Mozilla Firefox.. What is wrong here? Should I use another  html element here? How to check what browser the user is using also??

Comment: A question similar to this has already been answered.  
try looking into this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412467/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-php)

Comment: i quite have an idea about that but the main problem is checking the type of browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to directly embed a Flash object. The embed tag is an outdated one, which is mostly deprecated. ([Explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1244854).)  If you want a more reliable way to embed a Flash object, look into [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation).

However, an even better solution is to embed the video as an iframe. This way, YouTube will figure out the best way to embed the player, and you don't have to worry about browser detection. It will even use HTML5 video when necessary so it will work on iPads and other systems that don't have Flash.

The end result will look like this:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/U0x9HtYgVqA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

So your server-side code will look more like this:

```
echo '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $data['band_video_1'] . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

Just make sure `band_video_1` is the YouTube video ID and not the full URL.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking to check the browser, you could try some java script like so

```
<script type="text/javascript">'.
   var canPlay = false;
   var v = document.createElement('video');
   if(v.canPlayType && v.canPlayType('video/mp4').replace(/no/, '')) {
       canPlay = true;
   }

   alert(canPlay);

</script>
```