# Redirect Url Is Not Working with Iframe

Tags: html, redirect, iframe

What I Need:

- when user click on video url it must redirected to you video.
- we are using html5lightbox plugin .

problem im facing:

- redirection is not working in iframe.
- though when i click on src of iframe it is redirected to you tube url.

here is  html code

```
   <div id="html5lightbox-web" style="display:block;width:500px;height:400px;">

     <iframe width="500" height="400" src="http://t.co/hNLWmspb" frameborder="0">

        </iframe></div>
```

- i have tested on chrome its not auto redirected t particular page url.

problem explanation

- when user click on image video should be opened .

tweet data

```
    VW @ European Motor Show Brussels - Behind the scene (part 1): &nbsp;<a class="twtlnk" rel="nofollow" href="http://youtu.be/XzqagJTsNrc" target=\"_blank\">http://youtu.be/XzqagJTsNrc</a>  via &nbsp;<a class="twthand" href="https://twitter.com/youtube" rel="nofollow" target=\"_blank\" >@youtube</a>
```

here is code snippet

```
                 $media_url;// http://t.co/hNLWmspb




               $parsed = parse_url($media_url);
                print_r($parsed);

               Array ( [scheme] => http [host] => t.co [path] => /hNLWmspb 

                $ytarray=explode("/", $media_url);
                $ytendstring=end($ytarray);
                $ytendarray=explode("?v=", $ytendstring);
                $ytendstring=end($ytendarray);
                $ytendarray=explode("&", $ytendstring);
                $ytcode=$ytendarray[0];
                print_r($ytcode);

                if(preg_match('/http:\/\/(www\.)*youtube\.com\/.*/',$parsed['path']))
                {
                       // echo "YouTube URL found!\n";
                    $content='<div class="4u"><div class="box photo tile">
                 <a href='.$media_url.' class="html5lightbox" data-group=""
                   titl="'.$tweet_content.'">';
                }

                else
                {
                    $content='<div class="4u"><div class="box photo tile">
                    <a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/""'.$ytcode.' class="html5lightbox" data-group=""
                      titl="'.$tweet_content.'">';
                }
```

- i have taken help from [How to embed YouTube videos in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412467/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-php).

Comment: what do you mean by auto redirect? You don't have any link there, all you got is an iframe which includes youtube. Not quite sure if i understand what you're trying to do

Comment: issue is that when i click on html lightbox div . it does not redirect t you tube url .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server for the URL that `http://t.co/hNLWmspb` redirects to returns

```
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
```

in the HTTP response headers for the document you are trying to display in the frame.

This bans other sites (including yours) from showing the page in a frame, so the browser isn't rendering the page.

Use the official YouTube embed code instead.

Comment: how could i redirect page url to you tube if url is not you tube url

Comment: how to achieve -> http://t.co/hNLWmspb->redirected to youtube(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzqagJTsNrc&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: @user3785613 — That URL **does** redirect to that page. You still aren't allowed to display it in an iframe, but that has nothing to do with redirection.

Comment: i have problem in code <a href='.$media_url.' > where $media_url=http://t.co/hNLWmspb. problem  no video loads if there is no you tube url .

Comment: case when user click on image you video is opened , and no video is laoded where is there any way if we get url that not you tube and get be redirected through code to you tube url

Comment: ya i got your concept it working fine but issue arrise in iframe

Comment: what is the con concpt : x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN how could i solve this issue in iframe  any suggestion are most welcome

Comment: As I said in the answer - you can't put that page in a frame, so use their official embed code instead.

Comment: i have updated my code snippet please help when url is not you url i have appended this code /hNLWmspb .but it should be 11 characters. how its possible.